# Can I change parameters (period, autoReload) of a FreeRTOS software timer in its callback?

Tags: c, timer, freertos

I am using FreeRTOS software timer to execute code some time after a certain request.

For example I have a function reboot that starts a timer. The callback of this timer at first round does something (only once) and then changes the parameters of the timer in order to do different things at regular time intervals.
Here is the code of the reboot function:

```c
    void reboot(void)
    {
        /* here the timer is used to schedule a later call */
        if (NULL == xTimerRebootHdl)
        {
            xTimerRebootHdl = xTimerCreateStatic("rebootTimer", 25, pdFALSE, 0, vTimerRebootCallback, &xTimerRebootBuffer);
        }
        if (NULL != xTimerRebootHdl)
        {
            xTimerStart(xTimerRebootHdl, 50);
        }
    }
```

Which calls the following callback:

```c
    static void vTimerRebootCallback(TimerHandle_t xTimer)
    {
        static bool firstRound = true;

        if (firstRound)
        {
            // Do something
            xTimerChangePeriod(xTimerRebootHdl, 2000, 50);
            vTimerSetReloadMode(xTimerRebootHdl, pdTRUE);
            firstRound = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Do other things
        }
    }
```

Is it safe to change the parameters of the timer (period and reload mode) inside the own callback of the timer?

This code works but I would like to be sure I am not doing something erroneous.
FreeRTOS documentation does not say anything explicit about this issue.

Comment: I suppose it is safe, I can not see any problem with that. Also if you use CMSIS, you can just call osTimerStart(...)